# Get Page View Count for SharePoint 2013 in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, javascript

I'm new to SharePoint and am trying to figure out how to get a SharePoint page's view count. I am following this guide:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27069.sharepoint-2013-showing-page-views-within-a-sharepoint-page.aspx

Here is my code so far:

```
var context;
var web;
var list;
var currentItem;
function getPageViewCount() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    currentItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);
    context.load(currentItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededView),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedView)
    );
}
function onQuerySucceededView() {
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText('PageGuid:"{' + currentItem.get_fieldValues('UniqueId').UniqueId.toString() + '}"');
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    context.executeQueryAsync(SearchDone, SearchFailed);
}

function onQueryFailedView(sender, args) {
    //Error Logging
}
```

This is my error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined
    at onQuerySucceededView (data.js:349)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5
    at SP.ClientRequest.$32_0 (sp.runtime.js?rev=5f2WkYJoaxlIRdwUeg4WEg%3D%3D:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=VGnZ4IhGxDE3UL4BqAqm13Vs3hX7c15EyW3dFkx7WWEUXlD2hObd8zO-jiNQJcph_PRJcHvm7ho6jIpak67gAH06xRIDA91t-U_UwaghtLFMJPQJI5m_9C8oun1rCclNUnx9wxY0i9JCTyX_TfjlHN6LyKFr3ZSZO19TmUqAkqqaENXhdgGoVfUXuqHXa-tL0&t=10c151ff:5)
```

Comment: You might be missing the most important thing - adding the reference to SharePoints js files. Or your code is running before they are loaded.

Comment: "All the blocks explained above can be merged as working code and can be added to a page through a Script Editor Web Part, or can be added directly into a page layout which reflects in all the pages created using this layout. Also, reference to the following files needs to be added:

init.js
sp.runtime.js
sp.js
sp.search.js"

Answer (score 0):

Test below script in my local(insert script editor webpart into a page and insert the script into script editor webpart), you could try it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetPageViewCount, "sp.js");
    });

    var context;
    var web;
    var list;
    var currentItem;

    function GetPageViewCount() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
        currentItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId)
        context.load(currentItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert(currentItem.get_fieldValues("UniqueId").UniqueId);
        var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
        keywordQuery.set_queryText('PageGuid:"{' + currentItem.get_fieldValues("UniqueId").UniqueId.toString() + '}"');
        var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
        results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
        context.executeQueryAsync(SearchDone, SearchFailed)
    }

    function SearchDone() {
        var viewCount = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[0].ViewsLifeTime;
        //Use JQuery to show the viewCount on the page
        alert(viewCount);
    }

    function SearchFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
</script>
```